# UITableView bottom area keeps out of screen if navigationBar.translucent is NO;

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use UITableView instance as the subview of my ViewController's view, the table's content is higher than the screen so it is scrollable. Here is the code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opts {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

    // set to No cause the problem
    nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    return YES;
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test %u", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Now the problem is

- if `nav.navigationBar.translucent = YES`, the content is scrolling right, the bottom line is visible if I scroll to bottom.
- if `nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO`, the content isn't scrolling right, the bottom line automatically move out of the screen if I end the swip.

Seems like the auto hidden area is of the height of navigationBar, any one who knows how to fix it? I want it work the same no matter `translucent = YES` or `translucent = NO`.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Not auto layout

Comment: This is weird. Is there any possibility to share the source code?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman My mistake, I will clearify the quetion and paste the code.

Comment: Try changing "XIB > Attribute Inspector > Simulated Metrics > Size"

Comment: @RichaSharma Hi, I create the UI programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Try this & let me know if it works:

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I found out the solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution, I set the tableView as the mainview of the controller, not a subview of the controller's mainview

```
[self setView:_tableView];
```

instead of

```
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
```